# Multiple entity reference with Views

Tags: views, entities

I have a website about movies which are stored in a content type called Movie.
Amongst other fields, it's populated with Entity Reference fields such as Director, Actor, Writer, etc... linked to a content type called "Personnality".

For example, Johnny Depp can be referenced as a Director as well as an Actor in a movie called 'The Brave'.

In View, I'd like to list all his movies whether he's an actor or a director. Currently, I do it with several views but for a specific block, I want to feature the best movies of a personnality.

With relationships and contextual filters, I can only pick only one Item.

Is it possible to add multiple reference on the contextual filter ?

Here are some screenshots to help. It's in french, réalisateur = director, actor = casting.

[image: Node Description]

[image: View]

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `allow multiple values` in the **MORE** section of your contextual filter. (You can find it at the bottom).

For example:

[image]